# Custom font not working in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4

I have read lots of threads on how to get my custom fonts working in heroku.  They work locally in dev mode but when pushed to heroku they dont show up.

my @font-face located in master stylesheet

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'caviar_dreamsregular';
    src: font-url('caviardreams-webfont.eot');
    src: font-url('caviardreams-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         font-url('caviardreams-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         font-url('caviardreams-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         font-url('caviardreams-webfont.svg#caviar_dreamsregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Application.rb

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

I have precompiled assets with

```
rake assets:precompile
```

No errors in Heroku logs.

Cant figure this out, does anyone have any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Visited the site on my phone and the font works... Cleared cache on computer, still not working on computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be down to several issues; most notably, I would recommend you're not using dynamic asset paths:

---

**Fingerprinting**

Rails uses [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) when you precompile assets

The reason for this is to allow each asset to be individually allocated to the system, thus providing a more robust structure (or something). Basically, it adds an MD5 hash to the end of your asset filenames:

```
global-908e25f4bf641868d8683022a5b62f54.css
```

---

**Paths**

Because dynamic fingerprinting makes all precompiled assets have different names, you need to use Rails' dynamic path helpers:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss
@font-face {
    font-family: 'caviar_dreamsregular';
    src: asset-url('caviardreams-webfont.eot');
    src: asset-url('caviardreams-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset-url('caviardreams-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         asset-url('caviardreams-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         asset-url('caviardreams-webfont.svg#caviar_dreamsregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You'll need to use a dynamic stylesheet engine such as [SASS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/268-sass-basics) to handle the dynamic paths

Comment: My issue was I had the fonts in vendor/assets/fonts (and even with adding `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'fonts')` I couldn't get it to work). Once I moved the fonts to app/assets/fonts and re-deployed, they started working on Heroku!